# MW of installed capacity

Tags: power-electronics, energy, capacity

I am conducting research on wind turbines, specifically into how many hectares wind farms use.

I have come across the phase 'installed capacity'. If wind farms typically use up 10 hectares per megawatt of installed capacity does this mean a two megawatt turbine requires 20 hectares of land? Or does it mean the total power capacity of the windfarm?

Comment: Can you quote or link your source? The answer could be *yes* or *no*, depending on the context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> does this mean a two megawatt turbine requires 20 hectares of land?

YES

> Or does it mean the total power capacity of the windfarm?

NO the utilization for same input windspeed would be only 11% meaning, it takes 900% more windpower (3x speed) to achieve rated turbine output.

## Output/turbine declines with increasing capacity density

According to the [Planck Institute](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4568694/), others with previous estimates based on low density installed power, grossly under-estimated the loading factor of high density wind farm effects on output available.

A slim report on their study showed some key results which I have plotted below. It says when the density of Installed Power rises to 10W/m² the output/input available power ratio drops from 40% to 11%.

10 hectares per megawatt = 10W/m²
[image]
[image]
**Solar power generates 20 W/m²** – with no slowdown effect

Comment: who is the idiot -1 , I mean silent arm-chair critic who thinks they know better

Answer (score 2):

Have a read of David MacKay's excellent [Sustainable Energy Without the Hot Air](http://withouthotair.com/c4/page_32.shtml) Chapter 4, Wind. On page 33 he explains

> This conclusion – that the maximum contribution of onshore wind, albeit “huge,” is much less than our consumption – is important, so let’s
>   check the key figure, the assumed power per unit area of wind farm
>   (2 W/m<sup>2</sup>), against a real UK wind farm.
>
> The Whitelee wind farm being built near Glasgow in Scotland has 140
>   turbines with a combined peak capacity of 322 MW in an area of 55 km<sup>2</sup>.
>   That’s 6 W/m<sup>2</sup>, peak. The average power produced is smaller because the
>   turbines don’t run at peak output all the time. The ratio of the average
>   power to the peak power is called the “load factor” or “capacity factor,”
>   and it varies from site to site, and with the choice of hardware plopped
>   on the site; a typical factor for a good site with modern turbines is 30%.
>   If we assume Whitelee has a load factor of 33% then the average power
>   production per unit land area is 2 W/m<sup>2</sup> – exactly the same as the power
>   density we assumed above.

On the following page he answers the question

> *Wind turbines are getting bigger all the time. Do bigger wind turbines
>   change this chapter’s answer?*
>
> Chapter B explains. Bigger wind turbines deliver financial economies
>   of scale, but they don’t greatly increase the total power per unit land area,
>   because bigger windmills have to be spaced further apart. A wind farm
>   that’s twice as tall will deliver roughly 30% more power.

Comment: Peak power vs annual mean power with load factor, on a big scale is more important.

Answer (score 0):

Installed capacity typically refers to Nameplate capacity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nameplate_capacity

A two megawatt turbine does not necessarily require 20 hectares of land, it simply consists of a turbine whose rated power is two megawatts, that is, a turbine that is able to provide two megawatts of power.